# Passing Vargs from an inline function to a function

Tags: c++

I have 2 functions:

I received multiple arguments from the foo function and I simply want to send them to the myOtherFunction function. How can I do that please ?

```
static inline void foo(const char* str, ...)
{
    void myOtherFunction(bool A, int B, [VARGS]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In C++11:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void foo(const char* str, Ts&&...args)
{
    myOtherFunction(A, B, std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: And without cpp 11, how can I do ?

Comment: @panicq without C++11, there's no safe way of doing that.

Comment: without C++11, that requires that `MyOtherFunction` uses `va_list`, something like Maxim's answer.

Comment: Something difficult to interpret but very useful!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, by passing va_list as variable, example :

```
void func2(int n, va_list vl)
{    
  int i;
  double val;
  printf ("Printing floats:");  
  for (i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    val=va_arg(vl,double);
    printf (" [%.2f]",val);
  }  
  printf ("\n");
}

static inline void func1(int n, ...)
{    
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl,n);
    func2(n,vl);
    va_end(vl);
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    func1 (3,3.14159,2.71828,1.41421);
    return 0;
}
```